# Delete single model from collection in Backbone.View

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, collections, model

```
var PlayersView = Backbone.View.extend({
    collection: players,                //collection of players
    el: "#playersList",                 //I bind to the class
    render: function () {
        this.$el.html("");
        for (var i=0; i<this.collection.size(); i++) {
            var player = this.collection.at(i);
            this.$el.append("<li "+"value='"+player.get("id")+"'>"+player.get("names")[0]+" "+player.get("surnames")[0]+" <a href='#' class='edit'>[edit]</a>"+"</li>");
        }                            //what I render is in the picture below
        return this;
    },
    events: {
        'click .edit': 'edit',
    },
    edit: function () {
        console.log(???);         //what to write?
    }

});
```

[image]

Hey, I render an entire collection of players, which looks like list of names and [edit] button with each of them. When I click edit button how can I get a model from my collection of the exact player, that button stands next to? Is there a simple method or will I have to get parents field "value" that contains its id and then look for this id in my collection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to search the collection for the model's id.

Note that backbone will pass to your `edit` function as the first argument an object representing the click event. The `target` attribute of the click event will be the element that was clicked. It may be easiest for you to give the edit link an id property that matches your model's id.

```
var PlayersView = Backbone.View.extend({
    collection: players,                //collection of players
    el: "#playersList",                 //I bind to the class
    render: function () {
        this.$el.html("");
        for (var i=0; i<this.collection.size(); i++) {
            var player = this.collection.at(i);
            this.$el.append("<li "+"value='"+player.get("id")+"'>"+player.get("names")[0]+" "+player.get("surnames")[0]+" <a href='#' id='" + player.get("id") + "' class='edit'>[edit]</a>"+"</li>");
        }                            //what I render is in the picture below
        return this;
    },
    events: {
        'click .edit': 'edit',
    },
    edit: function (e) {
        this.collection.get(e.target.get("id"))
    }

});
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I did this another way: this.collection.get($(e.target).parent().attr("value")); I get id from its parent.